# Como converter hexadecimal para binário em uma matriz em r?

Tags: r, matriz, hexadecimal, números-binários

Eu tenho uma matriz com número hexadecimal, assim:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "FA" "F8" "D0"
[2,] "CE" "17" "6A"
[3,] "0E" "D6" "22"
```

Se eu tentar converter em binário, com `hex2bin(matriz) (biblioteca BMS)`, me é dado:

```
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [62] 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[123] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
[184] 1 0 0 0 1
```

Mas precisa de uma matriz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seguinte função talvez faça o que quer.
Primeiro os dados.

```
m <- matrix(c("FA", "F8", "D0", "CE", "17", "6A", "0E", "D6", "22"),
            nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Agora o código.

```
library(BMS)

hex2matrix <- function(M){
  R <- NULL
  for(i in seq_len(ncol(M))){
    B <- sapply(M[, i], hex2bin)
    R <- cbind(R, B)
  }
  R
}


hex2matrix(m)
```